# Nvim ставит размеры разделенных окон по умолчанию, после закрытия NERDTree

Tags: linux, vim

Всем привет, подсобите советом!
Я открываю neovim, и меняю размер окон на нужный мне.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом я открываю NERDTree
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после закрытия, размеры окон становятся по умолчанию.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это немного раздражает, и приходится менять размеры снова. Есть ли какое-то рабочее решение для того, чтобы зафиксировать размеры разделений, и не ебстись каждый раз с изменением размеров.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NERDTree тут ни при чем. Наблюдаете это поведение, как как у вас установлена опция `equalalways`. Вот что пишет докумендация:

> When on, all the windows are automatically made the same size after
> splitting or closing a window.

Отключите ее командой `set noequalalways`. Чтоб работало всегда, добавьте эту команду в `vimrc` файл.

Comment: ВАХ! Спасибо большое. Я даже не знал как загуглить. И уж тем более не догадался бы до этого сам